# WinJS filepicker light theme

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm developing a Windows 8.1 application. I use the "light" UI theme including in my HTMLs page a reference to the official Microsoft's CSS stylesheet "ui-light.css".

Everything works fine, except the background color of file pickers controls, which remains dark instead of light.

How can I set it to light ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: it is likely a windows setting if this is possible. i don't see that to be a option on control or the app. it seems that file picker does not use the app ui background color (put in manifest).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's out of app control to define background color for system file pickers. 
You can check official Twitter and SkyDrive apps, both display default dark background color for file pickers despite of different (lighter) app themes.